# Can a derived class define size of base class array in class declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have an abstract class that has an array data member, but the size is only known by the derived class.

Is this out-of-class-declaration assignment of the static constant ideal, or is there a way to specify that this constant data member must be defined by the derived classes? Is there a way to make the base class array a proper array, instead of a dynamic one?

```
class Edge {
    // composed of other objects
}

class Polygon {
public:
    Polygon() {
        edges = new Edge*[NUM_FACES];
        // Go on to populate array
    }

protected:
    static const int NUM_FACES;
    Edge** edges;
}

const int Rectangle::NUM_FACES = 4;

class Rectangle : public Polygon {
public:
    Rectangle() : Polygon() {}
}

const int Triangle::NUM_FACES = 3;

class Triangle : public Polygon {
public:
    Triangle() : Polygon() {}
}
```

And do I need to iterate through the array to delete its elements when I define the destructor or is that handled by the default constructor?

Comment: You have a lot of disparate questions. Try picking just one, if possible.

Comment: Your classes contain no arrays.  There are pointers all over the place, but no arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen templates:

```
template <unsigned int NUM_EDGES>
class Polygon {
...
private:
    Edge[NUM_EDGES] e;
};

class Triangle : public Polygon<3> {
};
```

If declared like this, `Edge()` and `~Edge()` will be called for each array element.

Comment: The issue with templates is that a `Polygon<3>` and a `Polygon<4>` are two totally separate types.  Maybe a good optimizing compiler can do some sort of magic to minimize the impact, but in general you are creating separate types, causing code bloat if there are different Polygon types.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, they *have to be* different types, because they have different sizes! You could make an edge-count-agnostic `PolygonBase` if you wanted, and have `Polygon<T>` inherit from that.